# VPN gateway + UFW killswitch + port forwarding

Tags: networking, vpn, ufw, lxd

I'm trying to set up a VPN gateway (using LXD containers). I'm using ufw for killswitch service. Almost all is working except port forwarding.

```
             ┌─────────────────────────┐                  ┌──────────────────────────┐
             │   SECOND CONTAINER      │                  │   OVPN CLIENT CONTAINER  │
             │                         │                  │                          │                ┌─────────────┐
             │     192.168.1.3         │       LAN        │       192.168.1.2        │    VPN TUNNEL  │             │
             │  gw:192.168.1.2     eth0├──────────────────┤eth0                 tun0 ├────────────────┤  VPN NODE   │
             │                         │                  │                          │                │             │
             │ HTTP test server in     │                  │                          │                └──┬──────────┘
             │        8107 port        │                  │                          │                   │
             └─────────────────────────┘                  └──────────────────────────┘                   │
                                                                                                      xxxxxxxxxxxx
                                                                                                   xxxx          xxx
                                                                                                xxx                x
                                                                                                 xx    INTERNET    x
                                                                                                   xxx           xxx
                                                                                                     xxxx    xxxx
                                                                                                        xxxxx
```

In my VPN gateway I have:

**ufw status**

```
192.168.1.0/24                ALLOW       Anywhere

192.168.1.0/24                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
Anywhere                      ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0
<myvpnremoteip> 1194/tcp      ALLOW OUT   Anywhere #vpn remote address
```

**before.rules** extract:

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8701 -j  DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

In **/etc/default/ufw**

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

I can access http://192.168.1.3:8701 directly, but I cannot access http://192.168.1.2:8107

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To make your issue easier to resolve, can you please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're using? Thanks